# What is the package manager under OpenSolaris 5.11?

Tags: solaris, opensolaris, packages, sunos

I'm on an OpenSolaris 5.11 server and when I asked about Django, technical support offered to use pkgin as a package manager.

```
[root@gpx8nnaa ~]# uname -a
SunOS gpx8nnaa.joyent.us 5.11 snv_89 i86pc i386 i86pc
[root@gpx8nnaa ~]# find / -name pkgin
[root@gpx8nnaa ~]#
```

This computer does not appear to have pkgin installed. How can I install a preferred package manager on this server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have an OpenSolaris 'server' to hand but the desktop I have handy has packagemanager (gui) and pkg (command line) installed. If you have access to packagemanager then you can add the webstack repository

```
gksu /usr/bin/packagemanager

    File->Manage Repositories
        Name: Webstack
        URL:  http://pkg.opensolaris.org/webstack
    Add
```

This should allow you to select the Webstack repository which contains Django.

If you don't have access to a GUI then you can install Django from the command line using pkg

```
pfexec pkg set-authority -O http://pkg.opensolaris.org/webstack webstack
pfexec pkg refresh 
pfexec pkg install Django
```

Note in place of `pfexec` if you have it setup you can use `sudo` or you can `su` to root and run the commands directly.

Comment: While correct for a real OpenSolaris system, your answer doesn't apply to the operating system used here which is a variant of the obsolete and discontinued  Solaris Express Community Edition released around April 2008. The Image Packaging System you are describing wasn't integrated in that release.

Comment: Thanks - I've only really touched the official releases.

Answer (score 4):

First, it appears you aren't really using a regular OpenSolaris distribution but kind of an old fork of it. `pkgin` is a pkgsrc front-end and is available on recent Joyent servers. On older ones, you should use `pkg_add` instead, and on even older ones using Blastwave as repository, `pkg-get` is the way to go.

Have a look at this page for details: http://wiki.joyent.com/display/smart/Joyent+Package+Repositories

Answer (score 1):

The official name of the OpenSolaris packaging system is IPS (Image Packaging System).  The primary command-line tool is pkg(1).  See http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Project+pkg/WebHome

jilliagre is correct: Joyent do not use an official release.  SmartOS is based on SXCE, which did not use IPS, but the older SVR4 package system from Solaris 10 and back.  Various third-party packagers such as Blastwave wrap SVR4 with their own package managers to handle things like automatic dependency installation which are not provided by SVR4 tools.